# What security implications should I consider in relation to mcollective?

Tags: appsec, manual-review

The use of PuppetLab's [mcollective](http://www.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/) is being planned by my company's SysOps team.  I will be reviewing their use of the tool and implementation of the system.

At this point I don't have a lot of knowledge regarding how mcollective works and would love to get somebody else's feel regarding security considerations/implications of the software.

Has anyone used or reviewed mcollective, and what did you find?

Comment: Have you reviewed it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For reference, PuppetLabs have their own security documentation for the product. I assume you've read it, but for the convenience of future data archaeologists [it's here](http://docs.puppetlabs.com/mcollective/security.html).